# Elements position fine in media-query: 380px - but not when resized from bigger width and down to 380px

Tags: html, css, media-queries

So I have two media queries: `MQ1. @media screen and (max-width: 380px)` and `MQ2. @media screen and (max-width: 768px)`.

1. When I run my browser in a start width equaling to MQ**1**. everything looks fine. If I then trigger MQ2 *(by resizing the browser wider)*. then MQ2. looks weird.
2. When I run my browser in a start width equaling to MQ**2**. everything looks fine. If I then trigger MQ1 *(by resizing the browser less wide)*. then MQ1. looks weird.

I am experiencing this behaviour in Crome, IE and on Iphone. For some reason it doesn't persist in Firefox.

My thought was that it could be an issue related to:

- Floats being defined to :none in the media queries / some issue with toggling this
- CSS3 animation position: absolute - top: values not being re-defined
  when new media query is triggered.

Could seem like a webkit issue, but not sure. Any ideas to what could be causing this issue?

I've put together a simplified test of all HTML/CSS here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HDvap

You can try resizing as mentioned in point 1 + 2 above and you will see the elements positioned differently from example to example.

TEST NOTE 1: When resizing down to 380px; (from wide width) notice that the black button will wrongly position/overlap upon the graphics for "text1"+"text2" and the whole content container will appear closer to the top.

TEST NOTE 2: When reloading in 380px; the black button will appear just fine

EDIT NOTE 1: I tried removing all related to animation in the CSS and the media queries worked perfectly. So could be a webkit specific issue with -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

Comment: I think the reason may be the `animation-fill-mode`. But as I never used it I cannot tell which behavior is the correct one. But to me both look strange compared to the description of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode#Values)

Comment: As I read it on MDN and see your reference to this- the issue could be that the end animation value from after executing will be remembered even though a new media query is triggered with another value - something like that?

Comment: Yes that's what I thought too, at least it somehow looks like that could be the effect. As I said, I never used `animation-fill-mode`, but it would be place where I would start to debug.

Comment: Thanks t.niese - I just removed all animation in the css and everything works fine with the media queries, so it is surely somehow related to animation - so will try and debug more :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because `@media screen and (max-width: 768px)` will overwrite `@media screen and (max-width: 380px)` as the condition in your 2nd MQ cover the condition of your 1st MQ...to avoid this conflict, instead of only `min` use both `min` and `max` for your MQ

```
@media (min-width: 380px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    /*
     styles only in range of 380 - 768px here
    */

  }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /*
     styles only in range of > 768px here
    */

  }
```

For same issue, I've added an answer today, you can check the explanation here : **[Media query css file not detecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751469/media-query-css-file-not-detecting/24752336#24752336)**

Comment: Are you sure this is the reason? I would guess it is `animation-fill-mode`. The layout should look the same no matter if the page is loaded at a given width or if it is resized to the given width.

Comment: Hi there and thanks a lot for your comment - appreciated!. I tried implementing this in my test case, but I still see the same test results by going through point 1 + 2. Ei. Looks fine initially in Crome smartphone size but making it wider it looks weird and vice versa.